# C Copying to a const char *

Tags: c, struct, strncpy

I have a project, and I was given a header file which contains:

```
typedef struct User_struct {
    const char *name;
    Friends amigos;
} User;
```

Friends is another struct that is not in the scope of my question

In a source file I need to create, I made a struct and subsequent global variable:

```
typedef struct UserList{
        User *user;
        struct UserList *next;
}UserList;

static UserList *users;
```

There is an initialization function `create_amigonet` in which I allocate memory to `users` and another allocation to `users->user`. My problem is with this function:

```
void addUser( const char *name )
{
        UserList *new_users;
        UserList *iter;

        if(users->user->name == NULL)
        {
                users->user->name = malloc(strlen(name));
                strncpy((users->user->name,name,strlen(name));
                return;
        }

        for(iter = users; iter != NULL; iter = iter->next)
        {
                if(iter->user->name == name)
                        return;
        }

        new_users = malloc(sizeof(UserList));
        if(new_users != NULL)
        {
                new_users->user = malloc(sizeof(User));
                new_users->user->name = malloc(sizeof(name)+1);
                strncpy(new_users->user->name,name,sizeof(name)+1);
                new_users->user->amigos = NULL;
                new_users->next = users;
                users = new_users;
        }
        return;
}
```

I need to copy a `const char *` into a `const char *`, and I am not allowed to change the definition of the User struct or the function. I am unsure how I am supposed to copy/initialize any nodes in my structure. I can change `UserList`, which is a struct I created as a linked list of "users".

Comment: `sizeof(name)+1` is not the length of the string, use `strlen(name) + 1`

Comment: Thanks. I already noticed that and changed it, but it's much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is going to lead to a problem:

```
users->user->name = malloc(strlen(name));
strncpy((users->user->name,name,strlen(name));
```

It seems you don't know about *null termination*.  Imagine you later want to read out of `users->user->name`. How will you know when the name ends? You didn't save the information `strlen(name)` anywhere.

For this reason, strings in C have a marker at the end of them. That marker is a null byte (byte of value `0`). Then, string handling functions know where the end of the string is (and usually, the end of the allocated memory).

So you need to allocate an extra byte, and use a proper copying function:

```
users->user->name = malloc(strlen(name) + 1);
strcpy(users->user->name, name);
```

As a rule of thumb, *never use `strncpy`*.  Either the `strcpy` or the `snprintf` function is more appropriate. `strncpy` is a relic from days of yore.

You have a similar (but even worse, since you lapsed into using `sizeof` without actually understanding what `sizeof` does) later in your program. Hopefully you can now fix that too, after reading my answer.

> I need to copy a const char * into a const char *,

You need to stop thinking of a pointer as "containing" anything. Pointers point to other parts of memory which must, in of themselves, exist.

You need to copy some bytes from one place to another, where you have pointers to both locations.

Now, you can't write to a location via a `const char *`. That's what `const` is for. However, the location is **not** in read-only memory: you just malloc'd it. So the location is definitely safe to write.  You just need to rearrange your code so you pass a non-const pointer to the writing function. One way of doing that would be:

```
char *new_name = malloc(strlen(name) + 1);
strcpy(new_name, name);
users->user->name = new_name;
```

Another way, if you are on a POSIX system, would be:

```
users->user->name = strdup(name);
```

which has the same effect.

Comment: `strdup` also won't do a copy when `malloc` fails, which is a check the OP missed.

Comment: This is also probably wrong: `if (iter->user->name == name)`. He should be using `strcmp(3)` instead.

Comment: Thanks. I already know about sizeof and the null character. I accidentally put up the code before I changed it, and I am aware of the differences, just a lapse in doing stupid things with my code. You did answer my question, though, about the copying.